# gdb watch a expr in a loop

Tags: gdb

code snippet:

```c
foreach(lc, vars)
{
    if (IsA(lfirst(lc), Var))
    {
        Var *var = (Var *) lfirst(lc);
        /* if system column, return error */
        if (var->varattno < 0)
            ereport(ERROR,
                    (errcode(ERRCODE_FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED),
                        errmsg("system column is not supported on incrementally maintainable materialized view")));
    }
}
```

what I tried:

```
(gdb) watch var->varattno
Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure pointer.
```

foreach will loop through. I want to see `var->varattno` when loop through.

Comment: Use `gdb`'s "[b]reak​ <function name or filename:line# or *memory address> " command to set a breakpoint at your `if (var->varattno < 0)` line, and set your `watch`, after `var->varattno` means something. Delete the breakpoint and continue. There are severeal `gdb` resources online.